# How do I change the markup only of a built-in widget?

Tags: customization, theme-development, widgets, html

I'm developing a theme and I'd like to slightly alter some of the HTML output of some of the built-in widgets. As of now, I managed to change the sidebar search widget by creating a `searchform.php` file in my theme -- though that might not only be the sidebar widget but alright.

I'm now onto the Archives widget. I literally just need to alter the bit that says "Archives" to change its tag and add a class. Do I really need to make my own (largely identical) class and register it and use my custom widget instead?

(If you can't tell, I haven't touched WP theming in around 10 years :)

Comment: I don't know widgets, but it looks like [you can set a 'title' property on the widget](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.5/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-archives.php#L44) that will override the 'Archives', and you can use 'before_title' and 'after_title' to pass HTML to wrap this in a tag.

Comment: I can do that for every widget in the sidebar which may be ok but I'd like to be able to customize individual widgets of possible.